# ExtJS, Hide a collapsed field when click the submit button

Tags: extjs

I am using ExtJS, and I have the following component:

```
var AlgoField = [{
    bodyStyle: 'padding-right:5px;',
    id: 'algo_id ',
    items: [{
        xtype: 'fieldset',
        title: 'Algorithms\' Field',
        autoHeight: true,
        collapsed: true,
        collapsible: true,
        items: [itemAlgo_1,
            itemAlgo_4,
            itemAlgo_3,
            itemAlgo_2
        ]
    }]
}]
```

I want to set the collapsed property to false, when occur an event, and I don't know how to get this property and set it to `false` . (I thought something like this: `Ext.get('algo_id').collapsed=false` but it doesn't work)

Please help me.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

You need to give the fieldset an `ID` and refer to it, not its parent, i.e:

```
var AlgoField = [{
    bodyStyle: 'padding-right:5px;',
    id: 'algo_id ',
    items: [{
        xtype: 'fieldset',
        id: 'collapse_this',
        title: 'Algorithms\' Field',
        autoHeight: true,
        collapsed: true,
        collapsible: true,
        items: [itemAlgo_1, itemAlgo_4, itemAlgo_3, itemAlgo_2]
    }]
}]
```

Then use:

```
Ext.getCmp('collapse_this').collapse();
```